# Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'FETCH_ASSOC' while setting PDO connection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here is my PDO connection class:

```
class DB {

private static $objInstance;

private static $dsn;
private static $user;
private static $pwd;


/*
 * Class Constructor - Create a new database connection if one doesn't exist
* Set to private so no-one can create a new instance via ' = new DB();'
*/
private function __construct() {}

/*
 * Like the constructor, we make __clone private so nobody can clone the instance
*/
private function __clone() {}

private function getConfig()
{
    $config = new Config();
    $db = $config->getConfig('dbcxn');
    DB::$dsn = $db['dsn'];
    DB::$user = $db['user'];
    DB::$pwd = $db['password'];
}

/*
 * Returns DB instance or create initial connection
* @param
* @return $objInstance;
*/
public static function getInstance(  ) {

    if(!self::$objInstance){
        self::getConfig();
        self::$objInstance = new \PDO(DB::$dsn, DB::$user, DB::$pwd);
        self::$objInstance->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        self::$objInstance->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    return self::$objInstance;

} # end method

/*
* Passes on any static calls to this class onto the singleton PDO instance
* @param $chrMethod, $arrArguments
* @return $mix
*/
final public static function __callStatic( $chrMethod, $arrArguments ) {

$objInstance = self::getInstance();

    return call_user_func_array(array($objInstance, $chrMethod), $arrArguments);

} # end method
}
```

I've taken the above from http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php with little modification of my own but when I call the class, I get this error:

`Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'FETCH_ASSOC'...`

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Instead of all the backslashes try adding `use PDO;` after your namespace declaration and see if that still throws the error - can't see anything wrong with the code so it's just a shot in the dark really

Comment: thanks FDL, that solve the PDO class not found issue but the Undefined class constant error remain. I added const FETCH_ASSOC = 2; and the error stopped but I still feel there is something wrong

Comment: Are you sure PDO is installed? :)

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk, yes, am sure, from the phpinfo() page.

Comment: Are you 3000% sure it says "`\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`"? No hidden zero-width spaces or other invisible stuff in there...? Try to retype it?

Comment: NOT \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC but Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'FETCH_ASSOC' @deceze

Comment: Yes, are you 3000% sure ***the code*** says `\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`? Not the error.

Answer (score -1):

becouse you don't have Config() class....

here:

```
$config = new Config();
```

you need to make that class first!

EDIT:
you need to define Config class!

like:

```
class Config
{
 // construct here
}
```